# How do you remove systemd-boot?

Tags: refind, systemd-boot

Today I installed fedora and rEFInd but the old boot options for systemd-boot from my old arch installation are still there. How do I safely remove these old components or at least hide the old entries?

Answer (score 9):

According to man(1) bootctl:

> `bootctl remove` removes all installed versions of systemd-boot from the
>   EFI system partition, and removes systemd-boot from the EFI boot
>   variables.

In addition to running `bootctl remove`, you can manually remove `/boot/loader`, the directory containing all of the configuration files for systemd-boot.